# Converting sparse file to non-sparse in place

Tags: files, sparse-files

On Linux, given a sparse file, how to make it non-sparse, in place?
It could be copied with `cp --sparse=never ...`, but if the file is say 10G and the hole is 2G
(that is the allocated space is 8G), how to make the filesystem allocate the remaining 2G without copying the original 8G to a new file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the face of it, it's a simple `dd`:

```
dd if=sparsefile of=sparsefile conv=notrunc bs=1M
```

That reads the entire file, and writes the entire contents back to it.

In order to only write the hole itself, you first have to determine where those holes are. You can do that using either `filefrag` or `hdparm`:

filefrag:

```
# filefrag -e sparsefile
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of sparsefile is 10737418240 (2621440 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0.. 1048575:  187357696.. 188406271: 1048576:            
   1:  1572864.. 2621439:  200704128.. 201752703: 1048576:  188406272: last,eof
sparsefile: 2 extents found
```

hdparm:

```
# hdparm --fibmap sparsefile

sparsefile:
 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 0; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
           0 1498861568 1507250175    8388608
  6442450944 1605633024 1614021631    8388608
```

This example file is, as you say, `10G` in size with a `2G` hole. It has two extents, the first covering `0-1048575`, the second `1572864-2621439`, which means that the hole is `1048576-1572864` (in 4k sized blocks, as shown by `filefrag`). The info shown by `hdparm` is the same, just displayed differently (first extent covers `8388608` 512-byte sectors starting from 0 so it's `0-4294967295` bytes, so the hole is `4294967296-6442450944` in bytes.

Note that you may be shown considerably more extents anyway if there is any fragmentation. Unfortunately, neither command shows the holes directly, and I don't know one that does such, so you have to deduce it from the logical offsets shown.

Now, filling that `1048576-1572864` hole with `dd` as shown above, can be done by adding appropriate (identical) `seek`/`skip` values and `count`. Note that the `bs=` was adapted to use the `4k` sectors as used by `filefrag` above. (For `bs=1M`, you'd have to adapt the seek/skip/count values to reflect `1M` sized blocks).

```
dd if=sparsefile of=sparsefile conv=notrunc \
   bs=4k seek=1048576 skip=1048576 count=$((-1048576+1572864))
```

While you could fill holes with `/dev/zero` instead of reading the hole of the file itself (which will also just yield zeroes), it is safer to read from the `sparsefile` anyway so you won't corrupt your data in case you got an offset wrong.

In newer versions of `GNU dd`, you may stick to a larger blocksize and specify all values in bytes:

```
dd if=sparsefile of=sparsefile conv=notrunc bs=1M \
   iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes oflag=seek_bytes \
   seek=4294967296 skip=4294967296 count=$((-4294967296+6442450944))
```

`filefrag` after running that:

```
# sync
# filefrag -e sparsefile 
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of sparsefile is 10737418240 (2621440 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0.. 1572863:  187357696.. 188930559: 1572864:            
   1:  1572864.. 2621439:  200704128.. 201752703: 1048576:  188930560: last,eof
sparsefile: 2 extents found
```

Due to fragmentation, it's still two extents. However, the logical offsets show that this time, there is no hole, so the file is no longer sparse.

Naturally, this `dd` solution is the very manual approach to things. If you need this on a regular basis, it would be easy to write a small program that fills such gaps. If it already exists as a standard tool, I haven't heard of it yet.

---

There is a tool after all, `fallocate` seems to work, after a fashion:

```
fallocate -l $(stat --format="%s" sparsefile) sparsefile
```

However at last in case of XFS, while it does allocate physical area for this file, it does not actually zero it out. `filefrag` shows such extents as allocated, but unwritten.

```
   2:        3..      15:    7628851..   7628863:     13:    7629020: unwritten
```

This is not good enough if the intent is to be able to read the correct data directly from the block device. It only reserves the storage space needed for future writes.

Comment: Or `cat sparsefile 1<> sparsefile`. You may be able to use `fallocate` on Linux to avoid having to write those NUL bytes if all you want is the space to be allocated.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks, forgot about `fallocate`. It has `--dig-holes` but no `--fill-holes`. However, it seems to work well enough when you specify the size. I will edit my answer.

Comment: On NFS or ext3 fallocate is not supported.

Comment: Newer `fallocate` have a `-z` which can be used in Linux 3.14 and above on ext4 and xfs (you'd need to run it with `-o` and `-l` for all the sparse sections I suppose).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yup, but this `-z` does not keep your data if you happen to get an offset wrong, so I'll stick to `dd` there...

Comment: The point on the actuall writing of the zeroes to the block device is interesting, but in most cases I think it is not a problem. After `fallocate` is executed `ls -laSh...` properly shows the space as allocated. The usual intent, say in virtualization cases, is not to use sparse files because of the overhead you pay at runtime, but still one can still distribute sparse files (as part of tar for example, which can encode them properly) and then before the first usage make them non-sparse

Comment: @Ivan, it may be better to just drop the sparse property when you untar then; less likely to produce a file with many fragments, which you usually get if you have a filesystem as a sparse file with holes all over the place. Then again, some virtualization solutions deliberately punch holes in files (TRIM support inside the VM) to save storage space on the host. Personally, I prefer giving real block devices to VMs instead of file containers.

Comment: @Ivan, also if it's a sparse filesystem image, you could just mount it and zero the free space inside of it, instead of using the complicated `dd` method above. It's the kind of detail you should have mentioned in the question... ;)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I tried cat with 1<> and got "cat: sparsefile: input file is output file"

Comment: @BrianMinton, yes, with the GNU implementation of `cat`, you'd need `<file cat|cat 1<> file` to work around that safeguard.